# View html code for a webpage on Tablets

Tags: android, html, browser

Like all Internet browsers allow users to view the HTML or other source code of any of the web pages they visit. All you need to do is view source code and there you go. I am currently using an Android Tablet on the Paypal website and wondered if there is a way to look up the code for it. The paypal website offers the pop-up screen on the top of the page saying download Android App. I want to know how to add this feature on my site.

Comment: I don't know how to view the source, but that feature is probably just some scripting (serverside or JavaScript) that tests the clients UserAgent string, and if it contains "android", it shows the message to download the app.

Comment: Hmmmmm!!! I would still love to know how they do it. . I wanna add this to mine. .

Answer (score 10):

Use this for Android Default Web Browser:

```
javascript:alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

And this for Android Google Chrome Browser:

```
view-source:http://www.yoursite.com
```

Answer (score 4):

I haven't found any view-source option on the default browser, but you can enter this into the url field to view source:

```
javascript:alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

You can change the user agent by entering "about:debug" in the location bar, then going to Settings - UAString.

Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera mobile browsers have the ability to be inspected though their desktop counterparts.

Answer (score 2):

You can install an App for this feature.

Just search Google Play (app store) for "view web source". The first App from Jamens Obrien is a very basic app that goes into your "share options".

So when you are surfing using your prefered Android browser. Either that is the default browser, Firefox, Chrome, Dolphin or Opera Mobile, just "share the page" and in the list of sharing options you now have a "View web source" option.

Once you select that, the new App opens the url and retrieves the HTML code for your viewing.

Hope this helps a lot of people. I see this problem over and over in here.

Comment: That probably won't work for any logged-in pages, or pages that give different output for different browsers.

Comment: True, the App will probarbly just download the page as a webclient itself. The solution for a logged in site would probarbly be a compiled version of the same browser. Eg. webkit with this view source feature enabled.

Comment: Webkit webviews don't have the browsers cookies, they have to be implemented. Otherwise it would be a security hole, any app could get your cookies/logins.

Comment: No, I was thinking recompiling the full webkit engine http://www.webkit.org/ not talking about a webview, but a full compiled browser with "view source" added.

Comment: That would be awesome, especially since you can't upgrade the built-in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Save the below code as a bookmarklet and open it whenever you want to view source of a page
`javascript:var s=document.documentElement.outerHTML;var w=window.open();w.document.body.innerHTML=s.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;<br/>");w.document.close()`

Comment: optimize for a little, `javascript:var d=window.open().document;d.body.innerHTML=document.documentElement.outerHTML.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;<br/>");d.close()` if one wants to have styled syntax, he can use [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) or [prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) in the bookmarklet

Comment: this is the one I'm using, `javascript:var d=window.open().document;d.write("<html><head><script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js'></script></head><body><pre style='word-wrap:break-word;white-space:pre-wrap;border-color:transparent' class='prettyprint linenums'>"+document.documentElement.outerHTML.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;")+"</pre></body></html>");d.close()`

Answer (score 0):

What if you install a plugin into a normal desktop browser that allows you to change/fake your user-agent string for the browser? then grab the one from your Android tablet and set that for your fake profile and then visit the website with it. Login, and then view source?

Firefox: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/

Google Chrome:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg

Comment: I used this method myself to see how public sites respond to mobile agents. Rather interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also prefix whatever URL you're visiting with "view-source:" (without the quotes) e.g. view-source:http://www.http://example.com

Comment: not working! Chrome and Lightning browser are adding "http://" before "view-source".
Tested on Sony Xperia